# Package a Linux system and app into an installable .iso? Kickstart?

Tags: linux, kickstart, iso

I have written a Python web app that has a number of dependancies. In addition to providing install instructions, I would like to package this up into an .iso for ease of installation.

Something similar to what [Fully Automated Nagios](http://www.fullyautomatednagios.org/wordpress/download/) does.

What is the best way to approach this? Is Kickstart what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why an ISO? Most administrators would *greatly* prefer to have a well-maintained deb or rpm package to deploy on their own OS instead of having to deal with a linux distro of unknown providence.

Comment: I could provide that *in addition to* other methods. My justification for an .iso is that I want to provide a fully installed system in as little time as possible. Like Turnkey Linux.